# saving entities that do not expose foreign key for their relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am little bit new in EF code-first. Let's say I've two entities as follows-

```
//Parent may have many childs
class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

//Child will have one parent.
class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName {get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent{ get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to save as -

```
var parent= db.Parents.find(1);
var child=new Child();
....
child.Parent= parent
db.Childs.Add(child);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But it gives me the following exception-

```
an error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key for their relationship.
```

Perhaps, I'm missing something here. Any help?

Comment: are you passing any null value within your entities?

Comment: @Valkyriee, No, I'm not.

Comment: @s.k.paul, try to use child.ParentId = parent.ParentId;

Comment: @itikhomi, that's ok. But I would like to do that way I am asking.

Comment: @s.k.paul, then extend your  public virtual Parent Parent get { return Parent; }

            set {
                Parent = value;
                ParentId = value.ParentId;
            } }

Comment: @itikhomi is right. Setting the parent property of child will not help, since the parent is defined by the `ParentId` property. You must assign the `ParentId`

Comment: You need to provide [mcve]. What you have posted currently just works (no exceptions). EF6.1.3

Comment: @TSungur this is not true. if the navigation property is set, relationship fixup will set the FK if it is not exposed, or it will throw an exception if the properties do not match. Regarding the problem at hand, I'd assume the Parent property is not mapped onto an FK, which will mean the FK is not exposed. Most likely the schema does not match the classes (in their current configuration) correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @DevilSuichiro, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the relation in fluent api? If not you must either define it via attributes or via fluent api. Like this:

```
//Child will have one parent.
class Child

{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ParenChildName {get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent{ get; set; }
}
```

Also setting the `Parent` property of child will not help, since the parent is defined by the `ParentId` property, you must set `ParentId=parent.ParentId`

Comment: You can set _either_ the Navigation Property or the Foreign Key Property.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I never even tried the first option before.

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, can I ask you something @DavidBrowne-Microsoft? If I set the navigation property Parent but the parent object is not attached what will happen? Will EF try to create the parent first in DB and then create the child entry?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would always attach to specify if the Parent is New or Unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DavidBrowne-Microsoft